# My app doesnt run in the Android simulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

So I'm developing a chatting app, and I have been testing it in an android simulator (the pixel 3 option). But now I'm trying to make it run in another emulator (this time I choose a pixel 2) and doesn't run.

***I will pass some of the code, including the MainActivity.***

*This is from the LogCat*

```
2020-01-28 01:47:27.799 10456-10456/com.example.textmefinal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.textmefinal, PID: 10456
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.textmefinal/com.example.textmefinal.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.textmefinal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

2020-01-28 01:47:57.456 10456-10494/com.example.textmefinal E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.textmefinal;
```

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ViewPager myViewPager;
private TabLayout myTabLayout;
private TabsAccessorAdapter myTabsAccessorAdapter;

private FirebaseUser currentUser;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference RootRef;
private String currentUserID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUser  = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("TextMe");

    myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs_pager);
    myTabsAccessorAdapter =  new TabsAccessorAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    myViewPager.setAdapter(myTabsAccessorAdapter);

    myTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (currentUser == null){
        SendUserToLoginActivity();
    }
    else {
        VerifyUserExistance();
    }
}

private void VerifyUserExistance() {
    String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if ((dataSnapshot.child("name").exists())){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                SendUserToSettingsActivity();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_logout_option){
        mAuth.signOut();
        SendUserToLoginActivity();
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_settings_option){

        SendUserToSettingsActivity();

    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_find_friends_option){
        SendUserToFindFriendsActivity();
    }

    return true;
}

private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {

    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
    //finish();
}

private void SendUserToSettingsActivity() {

    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);
}


private void SendUserToFindFriendsActivity() {

    Intent findFriendsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FindFriendsActivity.class);
    startActivity(findFriendsIntent);
}
```

}

**Log In Activity**

```
package com.example.textmefinal;
```

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressDialog loadingBar;


private Button LoginButton, PhoneLoginButton;
private EditText UserEmail, UserPassword;
private TextView NeedNewAccountLink, ForgetPasswordLink;

private DatabaseReference UsersRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    InitializeFields();

    NeedNewAccountLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SendUserToRegisterActivity();
        }
    });

    LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AllowUserToLogin();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
            {
                super.onStart();

                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (currentUser != null)
                    {
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                    }
            }

private void AllowUserToLogin() {
    String email = UserEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = UserPassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {

        loadingBar.setTitle("Sign In");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        loadingBar.show();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            String currentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

                            UsersRef.child(currentUserId).child("device_token")
                                    .setValue(deviceToken)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful())  {
                                                SendUserToMainActivity();
                                                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Logged in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}

private void InitializeFields() {
    LoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    PhoneLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.phone_login_button);
    UserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    UserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    NeedNewAccountLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.need_new_account_link);
    ForgetPasswordLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.forget_password_link);
    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

}


private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}

private void SendUserToRegisterActivity() {
    Intent registerIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(registerIntent);
}
```

}

**Register Activity**

```
package com.example.textmefinal;
```

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button CreateAccountButton;
private EditText UserEmail, UserPassword;
private TextView AlreadyHaveAccountLink;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference RootRef;

private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    RootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


    InitializeFields();


    AlreadyHaveAccountLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
    });

    CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CreateNewAccount();
        }
    });
}

private void CreateNewAccount() {
    String email = UserEmail.getText().toString();
    String password = UserPassword.getText().toString();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {

        loadingBar.setTitle("Creating New Account");
        loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating new account for you...");
        loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        loadingBar.show();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();


                            String currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).setValue("");

                            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("device_token")
                                    .setValue(deviceToken);

                            SendUserToMainActivity();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Account Created Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}

private void InitializeFields() {
    CreateAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    UserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
    UserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
    AlreadyHaveAccountLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.already_have_account_link);

    loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
}

private void SendUserToLoginActivity() {
    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(loginIntent);
}

private void SendUserToMainActivity() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}
```

}

**Can anyone help me?**

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9zbI.png)

Comment: share the logcat message.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the Run tab at the bottom of the editor, you should normally see a message written in red if the app encounters an exception. This message should tell you which error has been encountered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responsing, yes I have added a new ss with that, but the thing is that doesnt display any error

Answer (score -1):

you app TextMe has some issue at launcher activity that why it crash at start, please fix that... or share the logs of logcat so that we can help.

Comment: sorry for the lack of more information, I have updated the post with way more information. But the logs of logcat dont display any error, it is literally the app that does not open, it gets intalled but thats it

Comment: mAuth.getCurrentUser() is retuning null thats why at app launch you are getting null pointer exception when you invoke mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();